# How to share private meteor packages between multiple projects?

Tags: meteor

If you want to use a package between two projects, what's the best way to handle it.  Considering two scenarios :-

### First Scenario

Git Repository with the two projects like

```
root folder
    -- Mobile App Folder
    -- Web Folder
```

So both projets are in the same repository

### Second Scenario

Each project is in separate Git repositories and we want to share the package between those projects.

What's a good ways to handle each scenario?  ( Either using the same method for both, or different methods for each scenario)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to be aware of how Meteor handles package scanning when confronted with `meteor add package` :

- searching for it inside the local `packages/` folder of your app.
- searching for it inside every folder specified in the `PACKAGE_DIRS` environment variable.
- searching for it on Atmosphere.

Not sure about the specific order but I'm assuming the one that makes most sense.

So your question is basically where to store the package for an optimal workflow.

Using the fist scenario, you would store your private packages inside the app root folder under `packages/`, you'll just have to `git pull` from the repo to get the latest versions of the packages. Then you would have to make sure to define correctly the PACKAGE_DIRS env variable, something like this :

```
export PACKAGE_DIRS=$PACKAGE_DIRS:$HOME/meteor/my-repo/packages
```

Using the second scenario, you would store each private package on its own git repo, then pull them into a local `$HOME/meteor/packages` of yours and don't forget to set `PACKAGE_DIRS` appropriately.

```
export PACKAGE_DIRS=$PACKAGE_DIRS:$HOME/meteor/packages
```

I would tend to go with the second scenario if there's a chance that these private packages may be reused for other projects, if you are sure they only make sense in a particular project, then storing them along in the repo is OK.

Comment: where did this documentation come from btw?

Comment: It's not yet documented AFAIK, just happened to come across this by chance.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to symlink your shared private packages into the "packages" folder of each of your apps.

So assume you have have your shared package in the folder `/dev/mysharedpackage`. You could create a symlink via `ln -s /dev/mysharedpackage packages/mysharedpackage` and then add the package via `meteor add`.

Here is a Meteor Cast on this topic: https://www.meteorcasts.net/ep/3